# how do you properly call AWS Api Gateway from node?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to call AWS api gateway from NodeJS, using aws-api-gateway-client module.

Here is my code:

```
module.exports = function(app) {

    var apigClientFactory = require('aws-api-gateway-client').default;

    var querystring = require('querystring');

    var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
        apiKey: '1234'
    });

    var params = {
        //This is where any header, path, or querystring request params go. The key is the parameter named as defined in the API
        userId: '1234'
    };
    var additionalParams = {};

    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
    });

    app.post("/customerinfo", function(req, res) {
        console.log("name: " + req.body["customer_name"]);

        var body = {"async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "https://mystuff.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/staging/api",
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
            "cache-control": "no-cache"
        },
        "data": querystring.stringify(req.body["customer_name"])
    };

        apigClient.invokeApi(params, body, additionalParams)
            .then(function(result){
                // Add success callback code here.
            }).catch( function(result){
            // Add error callback code here.
        });
    });

};
```

As soon as I start the node server, I get this error:

```
/Users/eugene/Desktop/dms/node_modules/aws-api-gateway-client/dist/apigClient.js:84
  var endpoint = /(^https?:\/\/[^\/]+)/g.exec(invokeUrl)[1];
                                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at Object.apigClientFactory.newClient (/Users/eugene/Desktop/dms/node_modules/aws-api-gateway-client/dist/apigClient.js:84:57)
    at module.exports (/Users/eugene/Desktop/dms/app/routes.js:7:40)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/eugene/Desktop/dms/server.js:26:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:441:10)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
```

What is the proper way to call AWS Api Gateway from Node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are calling 'newClient' method of gateway client factory in your code:

```
var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
    apiKey: '1234'
});
```

It expects a key 'invokeUrl' in the configuration object. So you need to pass this key with your specified URL as value of this key. For example: you should try this -

```
var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
    apiKey: '1234',
    invokeUrl:'https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
});
```

Hope, it may help you to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

On an alternate path, why don't you directly call the API-Gateway's API as a rest call? Simply call the api url and pass key as 'x-api-key' in header. This will keep things simple and east to understand for other devs also.

Comment: It's the little things that matter.  This is a really great suggestion, depending on if it fits with your desired outcome.  In my case i was doing all this silly stuff like using identity pool tokens to try to call one of my apis from another.  Seeing this comment just made my solution much more elegant and secure.  I just set up a new endpoint protected by an API Key and i was done.  Thanks for this suggestion!